# Install version of Node on Linux

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, curl

I've launched an Ubuntu AWS EC2 instance and want to install Node 10.13.0.

I checked the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-cache madison nodejs
```

This only lists versions for 8.x. So I do this:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.13.0 | sudo -E bash -
```

Which gives me this error:

```
bash: line 1: html: No such file or directory
bash: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
'ash: line 2: `<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
```

Documentation online says to just do this:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

But this doesn't let me specify a version number. I've even tried this:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs=10.13.0
```

Which gives me this error:

```
Version '10.13.0' for 'nodejs' was not found
```

How do I achieve this in a couple of simple commands? Note that the LTS build is currently 10.14.0 and I want 10.13.0.

Comment: `curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.13.0` fails because the link leads to a missing page.

Comment: @ThursdayNext Yes that's correct. `curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x` this link does work but I'm not sure if that will just download the latest version e.g. 10.14 when I want 10.13. Do you know if this is the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Node Version Manager](https://github.com/creationix/nvm). No root privileges required.

Comment: Thanks. I do use NVM locally to switch versions between projects, but since my server only needs 1 version of Node, I wondered if this was unnecessary. Isn't there just a command to install the 1 version I need without using a third party tool like NVM?

Comment: In the absence of another easier technique, I'll accept this answer. I do still wonder why there isn't a simple method that doesn't rely on a 3rd party tool though.